# curly braces around for-loop alters output

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Working on *Eloquent Javascript* chapter on high order functions, I came accross this example:

```
function reduce(array, combine, start) {
  var current = start;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    current = combine(current, array[i]);
  return current;
}

console.log(reduce([1, 2, 3, 4], function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}, 0));
// → 10
```

which when the `for` loop is re-written to include, what I thought were optional, curly braces, like:

```
function reduce(array, combine, start) {
  var current = start;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    current = combine(current, array[i]);
    return current;
  }
}

console.log(reduce([1, 2, 3, 4], function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}, 0));
// → 1
```

the result is just 1 instead of the expected 10. What are the braces doing here to change the output?

Comment: The braces put the `return current;` run **within** the loop body, so on the first iteration, you exit the function. Without the braces, the `return current;` is **after** the loop body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to move the `return` statement outside of the block for the `for` loop, because the return statement ends the function and the loop immediately.

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    current = combine(current, array[i]);
}
return current;
```

```js
function reduce(array, combine, start) {
    var current = start;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        current = combine(current, array[i]);
    }
    return current;
}

console.log(reduce([1, 2, 3, 4], function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}, 0));
```

Answer (score 6):

The curly braces are doing just as you asked of them: because you included the `return` statement in the `for` loop:

```
function reduce(array, combine, start) {
  var current = start;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    current = combine(current, array[i]);
    return current;
  }
}
```

the loop stops short of what was intended because the return exits the loop, actually function when a value is returned, and so only the value of the array's first element: `1` gets folded to var `current` and outputs `1`. Whereas:

```
function reduce(array, combine, start) {
  var current = start;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    current = combine(current, array[i]);
  }
  return current;
}
```

returns the expected output: `10` because the `for` folds all array elements before returning a value.

Answer (score 3):

This code runs the loop once and returns right after the first cycle:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    current = combine(current, array[i]);
    return current;
}
```

Here we return after loop finishes cycling:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    current = combine(current, array[i]);
return current;
```